# RhEl 8.4 gui login getting stuck, screen pauses and mouse become unresponsive

Tags: login, root

I am having problem while login in root account of my rhel 8.4, screen frozes just after entering password. I have tried searching it's solution on internet. But nothing much is available there.

I can access root terminal login by pressing ctrl alt F1. And from there I have created user account , which I am using currently.
Plz give answer other than reinstalling system.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.